# How to parse an API response in Haskell Servant where content type header is not present?

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, servant

I am calling a 3rd Party API in Servant which doesn't specify a `content-type` header in the response. The response is just a line of text. Servant is failing to parse this response and throwing error response.

What would be the best way to either convert this to a `Text` or a defined type?

Answer (score 1):

When a servant client processes a response with no `Content-Type` header, it treats it like `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`.  To accept this content type, your API endpoint should use `OctetStream`, instead of `PlainText`, for the list of accepted content types.

So, your endpoint should look something like this:

```
type Api = "hello" :> Get '[OctetStream] ByteString
```

and your handler can return the raw `ByteString`:

```
getHello :: ClientM ByteString
getHello = client (Proxy @Api)
```

Comment: Any way to get this in Text directly instead of ByteString?

Comment: One way to do that is to `fmap` a decoding function over the `ClientM`, e.g. `fmap Data.Text.Encoding.decodeUtf8 (client (Proxy @Api))`.

Comment: Thanks @ollimandoliini, this worked, didn't realise we could do that. TIL.